# Keep the 'base level' in a regression with dummy values in Python/statsmodels

Tags: python, statsmodels

I am running a regression in Python using `import statsmodels.api as sm`.

Since my model contains dummy variables I have to drop a given level within each dummy variable group to avoid issues while running the regression.

However, I would like to include my 'ommitted' category or level in the summary results (`res.params`).

This is possible in R and Stata. How can I do this in Python/SM?

Comment: can you expand a bit on what is the intended outcome? In R I don't see how you will have the reference level category in the model summary

Comment: The purpose is to display base levels of factor or dummy variables in the results coefficient tables. I know a priori what the estimated coefficient will be; but I just would like it to be obvious in the results table (also helps remind the reader what 'level' or 'group' was omitted).